# How can a Groovy method return multiple times?

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to get the first K elements from a sorted map by the following piece of code:

```
//return top rank k elements
public static LinkedHashMap<String,Double> getTopRank(int i){
    //store top k elements
    LinkedHashMap<String, Double> result=new LinkedHashMap<>();
    int count=0;
    //use the static rankMap in the class
    rankMap.each {key,value->
        result.put(key, value);
        count++;
        if(count>=i){
            println "Time to return"
            return result;
        }
    }
    //in case the loop does not work
    return result;
}
```

What I expect is that when the result Map already has a size of i elements, the method will return, giving me a i-size sorted map. Note that `rankMap` stores the elements in a certain order I want, and its size is far bigger than int i I pass to the method.
And I'm calling the method by

```
LinkedHashMap<String,Double> content=getTopRank(outputSize);
```

But unexpectedly finally the content had the size of `rankMap` rather than `i`! And in the console I saw hundreds of `Time to return` lines. The line `return result` was executed again and again until it reached the end of `rankMap`. 
I'm pretty sure that the line `getTopRank(outputSize)` was not in a loop. Then it seems strange to me why this method can return multiple times without ending. Is it caused by my putting `return` statement in the closure?
Please advise or tell me how this is true in Groovy. One step further, how can I get only first k elements from a sorted map then?

Comment: use collect instead of each you can achieve your goal by that

Comment: collect won't help much

Comment: Some languages have "yield" concept, Groovy hasn't. Some SO discussions exist,(disclaimer can't say about quality) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743472/workaround-for-lack-of-generators-yield-keyword-in-groovy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstood key concepts of Groovy.

The only way to finish the `each()` execution before reaching the end, is to throw an exception. If your want to exit the loop conditionally, use standard loop types like `for` or `while`:

```
int count=0
def result = [:]
for( def e in rankMap ){
  count++
  result[ e.key ] = e.value
  if( i <= count ) return result
}
```

Comment: myMap.take(i)  is more Groovy-like

Comment: sure. the question was about `returning` from closure, that's why I put `for()`

Comment: Your explanation of each() was spot on. Your solution also was a working version of the example. But it's pretty obvious OrlandoL comes from a Java background without much Groovy experience (or a reference to the Groovy Docs). I felt a push towards the correct Groovy method would be more beneficial than fixing it in the language they're already familiar with.  Your solution doesn't encourage reading any documentation, which is really what the question boiled down to.

Comment: well, my solution DOES encourage reading the documentation, because without knowing how the very basic groovy collection methods work, you can't really proceed efficiently

Comment: btw, `map.take i` is even groovier ;)

Comment: @injecteer damn, `map.take` nails it.

Answer (score 2):

The method itself is not returning. `each` is a method which receives a closure. Closures have their own returning context, which is not tied to the method who invoked them, thus, the loop is not broken.

I'd like to suggest getting a range from the map's `entrySet` and collecting the resulting entries:

```
def getTopRank(int i) {
    rankMap
        .entrySet()
        .toList()[0..<i]
        .collectEntries()
}

rankMap = [
    'Beatles'        : 'The White Album',
    'Pink Floyd'     : 'The Dark Side of the Moon',
    'Rolling Stones' : 'Sticky Fingers',
    'The Doors'      : 'Morrison Hotel',
    'Bob Dylan'      : 'Bob Dylan'
]


assert getTopRank(2) == [
    'Beatles'    : 'The White Album',
    'Pink Floyd' : 'The Dark Side of the Moon']

assert getTopRank(4) == [
    'Beatles'        : 'The White Album',
    'Pink Floyd'     : 'The Dark Side of the Moon',
    'Rolling Stones' : 'Sticky Fingers',
    'The Doors'      : 'Morrison Hotel',]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static LinkedHashMap<String,Double> getTopRank(int i){
    rankMap.take(i)
}
```

http://www.groovy-lang.org/gdk.html
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#take(int)

Comment: be aware that `take()` is available since groovy `1.8.1` which might be a problem in an old-fashioned setup. Also, there's a gotcha here, as the `map` should be an instance of `LinkedHashMap`, otherwise you'll get random results